# Eclipse CDT unresolved atomic types

Tags: eclipse, multithreading, c++11, stl, atomic

OS: OSX Mavericks
C++11.
I've included < atomic > header, but Eclipse CDT cannot resolve atomic types. 
My code compiles successfully, but it's really annoying when it's syntax checker underlines my code with red and says "Type 'atomic' cannot be resolved.". 
I don't want to disable indexer because autocompletion depends on it.
Tried checking the header inclusion by Cmd+LeftClick on . 
Eclipse CDT opened it and showed me, that it sees the header.
Then I've found the possible error location. 
What I can do to fix that? 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWPJr.png

Answer (score 0):

- add `std=c++11` to compiler options
- use [lastest milestone version of CDT](http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/downloads.php) with better C++11 support. Update site for milestones: http://download.eclipse.org/tools/cdt/builds/luna/milestones

Comment: I'm using a custom Makefile project setup, not Eclipse's Makefile.  And I already have the latest Eclipse CDT setup and C++11 flag. The problem is that Eclipse's indexer doesn't see that type

Comment: @nmindiedev Latest release version (that you probably using now) is not the same as latest milestone. If milestone will not work for you, try nightlies.